# Uncaught TypeError: target.className.indexOf is not a function at HTMLDocument.triggerTranslation

Tags: html, reactjs

Why i got this error? I wanna create menu for mobile devises, but i do not have enough experience for this, so i decided to try to do something like this:

```
function Header() {
  const [menuIsClicked, setmenuIsClicked] = useState(false)
  const auth = useContext(AuthContext)
  const clickMenuHandler = (menuIsClicked) => {
    if (menuIsClicked) {
      return setmenuIsClicked(false)
    }
    return setmenuIsClicked(true)
  }
 
  return (
    <>
      <header className="hd-home">
        <MenuForMobiles menuIsClicked={menuIsClicked} clickMenuHandler={clickMenuHandler} />
        <div className="nav-link1">
          <a href="/" className="nv-btn">Home</a>
          <a href="" className="nv-btn">About</a>
          <a href="" className="nv-btn">Donate</a>
        </div>
        <div className="nav-link2">
          <a href="/donate" className="nv-btn">Profile</a>
          <a className="nv-btn"
            href=""
          >Exit</a>
        </div>
      </header>
      <a href="">
        <WeeklyNews />
      </a>
    </>
  )
}


function MenuForMobiles(menuIsClicked, clickMenuHandler) {
  if (menuIsClicked) {
    return (
      <div className="m-o"
        style={{
          backgroundColor: 'pink',
          width: '100vw !important',
          height: '100vh !important',
        }}>
        <i onClick={() => clickMenuHandler}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faListUl} />
        </i>
      </div >
    )
  }
  return (
    <div className="m-o">
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faListUl} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

I think that a problem is on my `clickMenuHandler` function.
Thx for any advices and help. By the way, as you can see, i am new on react :)

Comment: Didnt fount any issue in the above code, check where you are using `target.className.....`

Comment: @sojin i dont use `target.className` at all, i think it something that what `react` does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this error can be caused by plugins in your browser. In my case it was google translator. I just removed it cuz i don't use it, but will be better if you'll try to ignore/catch this error.

Second, you can use source code like this to make things like `DropDownButton`

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/buttons/dropdownbutton/